# How to use opencv header in visual studio windows app

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I did my work in visual studio 2010 c++ console , but now i am trying to convert my work into windows app (making interface of it) in visual studio c++ . For that i have to add some header files which i have to add manually in windows form application, like

[image]

and it show me some error's in it like

```
DetectRegions.h(10): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'filename'
DetectRegions.h(10): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
DetectRegions.h(10): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
DetectRegions.h(11): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'
DetectRegions.h(14): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
DetectRegions.h(14): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
DetectRegions.h(14): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
DetectRegions.h(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
DetectRegions.h(16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
DetectRegions.h(16): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
DetectRegions.h(17): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'RotatedRect'
DetectRegions.h(18): error C2653: 'cv' : is not a class or namespace name
DetectRegions.h(18): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'histeq'
DetectRegions.h(18): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
DetectRegions.h(18): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Mat'
DetectRegions.h(18): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
DetectRegions.h(18): warning C4183: 'histeq': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
```

`Plate.h` is same like `DetectRegions.h`

I add the other headers of `opencv` in Form1.h like

```
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp" .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using std::string and std::vector in DetectRegions.h, but aren't including their headers

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

Likewise, you need to include the cv headers there if you're using them there.

Comment: Than why these errors are for 
`DetectRegions.cpp
DetectRegions.cpp(1): warning C4627: '#include "DetectRegions.h"': skipped when looking for precompiled header use
          Add directive to 'StdAfx.h' or rebuild precompiled header
DetectRegions.cpp(214): fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "StdAfx.h"' to your source?`

Comment: You've got precompiled headers enabled in your project's settings.  This requires the first `include` to be `#include "StdAfx.h"` at the top of every cpp file.  Add that and it should be ok.  (The error message you've pasted, in it's slightly overly wordy way, tells you exactly that)